# Get month from database and sent to another page using javascript /ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax

we are facing problem to get month form database that have already posted, in another page using javascript get method...
when page redirect to another pag, the output is 2008, and its false, while true value is 2018-10. 
here is code

```
 <input type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-md' 
    onClick='print_all_vouchers($session,$get_month)' value='Print All'/>

function print_all_vouchers(session_id,months){
    $('#loading_img').fadeIn('fast');
    $.get('ajax/vouchers.php? 
    session_id='+session_id+'&months='+months,function(data){
        $('#loading_img').fadeOut('fast');
        data=$.trim(data);
        if(data!=''){
            $('#print_this').html(data);
            $('#print_this').printThis({printContainer:false});
        }
        else{
            alert('Error');
        }
    });
}
     //------vouchers.php------//
       <?php
       if(isset($_GET['months'])):
       echo $month = $_GET['months'];

      if(isset($_GET['session_id'])): 
      $session_id= $_GET['session_id'];?>
     <?php endif;?>
     <?php endif;?>
```

Comment: the month value have actually 2018-10

Comment: I don't think there is enough information to solve your problem.  I'd start by running the SQL on your database to see if the information actually returns what is expected, then run the get query manually to test, then check the log files to see if anything fishy is going on.